# Do multiplication with jQuery based on checkboxe and drop down selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, multiplication

I need to do a maths calculation based on a user selecting a drop down option and choices from checkbox items on my register form.

I have a drop down option labelled "Type of listing required" and contains two options:

- Featured (£25 per month per area)
- Standard (£10 per month per area)

We also have 3 checkbox items underneath this drop down which are labelled "Which area/areas do you serve?":

- Altrincham
- Hale
- Sale

After a user has selected an option from "Type of listing required" and their choices from "Which area/areas do you serve?" I want to show a total price to them before the submit button.

The calculation is ("Type of listing required") multiplied by the number of ("Which area/areas do you serve?")

So if a user selects "Standard (£10 per month per area)" then ticks **ALL** 3 checkbox options (Altrincham, Hale, Sale) I want to show a message that says "The total cost is £30 per month". This would be the result of £10 times 3.

If a user selects "Featured (£25 per month per area)" then ticks **ANY** 2 checkbox options (Altrincham, Sale) I want to show a message that says "The total cost is £50 per month". This would be the result of £25 times 2.

If a user selects "Featured (£25 per month per area)" then ticks **ANY** 1 checkbox option (Hale) I want to show a message that says "The total cost is £25 per month". This would be the result of £25 times 1.

How would I go about this in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can resolve it is by having a function that reads all the values you need into different variables.

Then check each variable for the expected value and do the calculations accordingly. Yoy will store the result in another variable.

And finally you will set the value of the UI element using the variable.

How you trigger this function?

It can be done based on pressing a button, or when the value of an element is changed. In the first case you will use $().click(function(){...}) and in the second case $().change(function(){...}).

To get the value from an element you use $().val() and to set it, the same but passing a value in the function ( val(newValue) ).

Summarizing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function doCalculations(){
    var input1 = $(input1selector).val();
    ...
    var result = 0;
    if( ){
       ...
       result = ...;
    }else if() {
       ...
       result = ...;
    }else{
       ...
       result = ...;
    }

    $(uiOutputSelector).val(result);
};

$(calcButtonSelector).click(function(){
    doCalculations();
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about which of the cities were checked, just how many of them.

You can listen to the `change` event on the three checkboxes for each checkbox, you can increment the count when it gets checked, and decrement it when it gets unchecked.

After modifying the count, you can call a function that will render the total if the total is >1 or hide/delete the total price if total is 0.

Of course, I won't write any code for you since I don't know what your markup looks like and what JavaScript code you may have already written.